# how to create a RRD Graph but only the inerrors and outerrors data are displayed?

Tags: fetch, rrdtool

```
rrdtool graph port-6.rrd
```

[Here info for port-6.rrd: how to make a graph from this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoU72.jpg)

Comment: If you can share port-6.rrd file, I can help you